# Keep powerpoint running minimized

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

Using powerpoint 2013

I have a looped powerpoint with animations playing on one of my 2 displays. I want to be able to do something on display 1 (lets say editing a word doc) while the powerpoint is running on display 2. I can minimize the presenter view and work on something else fine, but then the animations on the powerpoint stop. Is there any way to keep animations on the powerpoint running while working on something else?

Thanks

Comment: Generally, no.  But have a look at PowerShow and the other add-ins at http://officeone.mvps.org  I believe Chirag has one or more that allow you to use the computer for other purposes w/o stalling the slide show.

Comment: well, i ended up exporting it as a video and running that looped on the external screen, which worked for my purpouses